Как сделать вкл/выкл цикла while в python с помощью pyautogui и pyqt5?
у меня есть функция, которая запускает бесконечный цикл while, я смог сделать, чтобы я мог его остановить, но у меня не получается сделать остановку и включение цикла (паузу)
Main.py:
class Thread(QThread):
    value_changed = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, login):
        super().__init__()
        self.login = login
        self.running = True

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('login.db')
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

        coord_x = self.cur.execute(
            'SELECT coord_X FROM settings_autoswap WHERE login = ?',
            (self.login,)).fetchone()
        coord_y = self.cur.execute(
            'SELECT coord_y FROM settings_autoswap WHERE login = ?',
            (self.login,)).fetchone()
        button = self.cur.execute(
            'SELECT button FROM settings_autoswap WHERE login = ?',
            (self.login,)).fetchone()
        color = self.cur.execute(
            'SELECT color FROM settings_autoswap WHERE login = ?',
            (self.login,)).fetchone()
        pause = self.cur.execute(
            'SELECT pause FROM settings_autoswap WHERE login = ?',
            (self.login,)).fetchone()
        stop = self.cur.execute(
            'SELECT stop FROM settings_autoswap WHERE login = ?',
            (self.login,)).fetchone()
        x = coord_x[0] if coord_x else None
        y = coord_y[0] if coord_y else None
        b = button[0] if button else None
        c = color[0] if color else None
        p = pause[0] if pause else None
        s = stop[0] if stop else None

        while self.running:
                # Ваш основной цикл
                Color = pyautogui.screenshot().getpixel((x, y))
                print(Color)
                if str(Color) == str(c):
                    print('swap')
                    pyautogui.press("2", presses=b, interval=0.01)

                # Проверяем, нажата ли клавиша для остановки цикла
                elif keyboard.is_pressed(p):
                    self.running = False


А как технически выглядит пауза цикла? Чем это отличается от простой остановки и запуска цикла?

Она ставит просто на паузу цикл и может его возобновить, но польностью она не выходить из цикла и функции

Мне надо, чтобы я на одну и ту же кнопку мог и останавливать цикл и запускать, скажем так

Garetj 37, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.
